# Click in Angularjs using Casperjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, casperjs

I would like to click in angularjs using casperjs. However, i cant achieve this. The webpage populates a dialogbox everytime i run so this is why i need to click.

**This is what i try to click**

```
<button class="ng-scope" trans="" ng-click="closeDialog(activeDialog, 'okButton');$event.stopPropagation();" ng-if="!activeDialog.yesno">Tamam</button>
```

**This is what i use in casperjs**

```
casper.then(function () {
this.evaluate(function() {  

    $($(document).find('button[ng-if="!activeDialog.yesno"]')).click();
});

this.wait(3000);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the code below:

```
casper.waitUntilVisible('.close-j',function(){
   this.click(x("//a[@ng-show='!activeDialog.hideCloseButton']"‌​));
   this.wait(5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it this way also:

```
this.click('button[ng-if="!activeDialog.yesno"]');
```

I had similar problem. Every time I login to the website a popup window opens and I have to put certain value text field and click button. That's how popup window class and other attributes looks like:

```
<button class="md-raised md-primary md-button md-button md-ink-ripple" aria-label="Okey", type="button">
```

That's how I solved it:

```
this.waitUntilVisible('button[aria-label="Okay"]', function () {
    this.click('button[aria-label="Okay"]');
    this.echo("########### Okay button clicked")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the attribute value in the selector. You can either give your button a unique class or id to select it:

```
<button class="yesno" trans="" ng-click="closeDialog(activeDialog, 'okButton');$event.stopPropagation();" ng-if="!activeDialog.yesno">Tamam</button>
```

and

```
this.evaluate(function() {  

    $($(document).find('.yesno')).click();
});
```

or if there is only one button just use:

```
this.evaluate(function() {  

    $($(document).find('button[ng-if]')).click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But both of them did not work. I get this error when i try "Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting. "

Comment: that is a different issue, you are probably calling that before angular finishes loading, so either try to increase the timeout or find a way to post pone your call until the loading is finished @Quicksilver

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer. I solved this problem using codes below

casper.waitUntilVisible('.close-j',function() {
     this.click(x("//a[@ng-show='!activeDialog.hideCloseButton']"));
    this.wait(5000);
});

Comment: @Yaser What if the button doesn't have any unique class or id? I think it shouldn't be a problem if attribute value is used.

Comment: @johnshumon  you're right but only if there is one button found by that query